# ERROR Object of class PDO could not be converted to int

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statements

tengo este codigo de PHP usando PDO, pero me marca la siguiente excepcion
"Object of class PDO could not be converted to int"
y no entiendo por que? podrian explicarme por favor ya que lo he revisado en internet y no debería soltar una excepcion.

```
 public function getNrec($nik)
{
 try {
    
     $sql = $this->conexion->prepare("SELECT `nombre` FROM recursos WHERE id=?");
     $sql->bindValue(1, $nik,PDO::PARAM_INT);
     $sql->execute(); //aqui aparece la excepcion
     $row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
     $sql=null;
     return $row['nombre'];
 } catch (Exception $e) {
     
 }
```

}

Comment: Puedes hacer un var_dump de $nik justo al principio de la función para que veamos que tipo de variable estas mandando? Viendo el error que obtienes yo diria que no estás mandado el dato que quieres.

Comment: es un entero y el id de la tabla recursos para consultar un recurso

Comment: y en qué línea es el error? qué versión de PHP?